# Why is res.rows undefined?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, postgresql

Essentially, I'm just trying to get the rows that satisfy the condition in the SQL line but for some reason am getting back this error that says

> 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined'

--I thought it was because maybe my table was named something else and I made a typo, but the table name is correct...

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const db = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});

db.connect();

let SQL = 'SELECT rowid,* FROM featurestable WHERE timestamp > ($1)'

function featureArrayHelper() {
    let currentDate = new Date()
    let date = ("0" + currentDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
    let month = ("0" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    let year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    let hours = currentDate.getHours();
    let minutes = currentDate.getMinutes();
    let seconds = currentDate.getSeconds();
    let currentTimestamp = year + "-" + month + "-" + date + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds

db.query(SQL, [currentTimestamp], (err, res) => {
  console.log("res.rows is " + res.rows) //res.rows here is undefined?
  for (row of res.rows) {
    console.log("Row found")
  });
}
```

Comment: There is an err.  Look in "err" to see what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of `err`, it's likely that something's going wrong if `res` is `undefined`.

Comment: This was the simplest thing to do. Apparently Postgres rows don't have a rowid property so my SQL command wasn't functioning correctly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First Check value of `res`, check it has `rows` value or not